# How select the rest of the word in incremental search in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: search, ide, intellij-idea, incremental-search

When in incremental search mode in Intellij IDEA, is there a way to select the rest of the word. For example, suppose I want to find the word “handleReservationGranted”. I type Ctrl-f to enter incremental search mode, and start typing the letters “han”. Now suppose I have found the beginning of “handleReservationGranted”. In my search box I have “han”, but I would now like to be able to select the rest of the word, so that the search box contains “handleReservationGranted” instead of “han”.

In Xemacs, I can type Ctrl-s, type “han”, and then type Ctrl-w. Now my search term is “handleReservationGranted”, and not “han”. So now if I press Ctrl-s, I find the next occurrence of “handleReservationGranted”.

Is there a similar feature in Intellij IDEA? The best I can do now is either to keep typing in the rest of the letters (dleReservationGranted), or exit incremental search, select the word with Ctrl-W, then enter search again with Ctrl-f.

I am using Intellij IDEA 7.0.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use autocomplete during an incremental search.

After you type "han", press CTRL-SPACE (autocomplete) and it will give you a list of potential matches in the file.  Just pick "handleReservationsGranted" from the list and that will become your search term.